# How To Delete a Document Using a Workflow Defined in Information Management Policy

Tags: workflow, document-library, information-management

Wondering if someone can help point me to any posts that talk about how to create a Workflow that emails a person asking if a document can be deleted.  I am looking for the Workflow to generate the email, based on the user response, the document will be kept or deleted.

The overall goal is to use this Workflow in an Information Management Policy retention stage event.  I need to delete documents using the Last Modified field (documents not modified in over 5 years need to be deleted).

This seems like a fairly common thing.  I just cannot find anything.  I have googled for a bit and have come up empty handed.

Thanks for any information provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy solution would be to use the OOTB functionality:

1. Create a task list for task about deleting
2. Set an alert for the person who should notified
3. Add a Disposition Approval Workflow to the DocLib using the newly created task list
4. Set retention to start this workflow

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have the workflow that is called by IRM create a task for a user.  One of the fields in the task will need to be a Retain field with yes and no options.  When the task is completed, the workflow looks at the completed task, if they said no then it can be deleted, if they say yes, the workflow ends and does nothing.

Comment: Thanks PirateEric.  I am actually looking for steps on how to create this Workflow.  Thanks for the comment.